# Content Search - Display only custom library templates types

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope, kql

I am trying to get a Content Search WP to return only Doc Libraries created using a custom Library template. I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
contentclass=STS_List_CustomTemplateName IsDocument<>True
```

Adding `_CustomLibraryName` to `STS_LIST` doesn't seem to do the trick, is there another managed property for custom library templates or an alternate approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try with the content types. Limit the search results for respective content types.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Unfortunately there are no custom content types, just Document. There are set of libraries in a site created using a custom library template in SP 2013 and ideally only those libraries should appear in Content Search webpart.

Comment: List name starts with or ends with or contains???

Comment: Naveen, I'm not sure if you are asking me a question?

Comment: I am asking you to try those functions

Comment: I don't think you understood the question, I cannot filter results on List/Library name because I'm trying to display all libraries which use a specific library template (custom) hence I tried the contentclass property